# r tables package: pass an argument to the Headings pseudo function

Tags: r

I would like to pass a value using a variable into the pseudo-function Heading, such as

```
mystring <- "My column header"
latex(tabular(Heading(mystring)*factor ~ ...
```

but the result is that instead of the contents of `mystring` the column head is set to "mystring".

for the sake of a reproducible example

```
tabular(Heading("Column Heading")*(Species + 1) ~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2)*(Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)*(mean + sd), data=iris)
char <- "Column Heading"
tabular(Heading(char)*(Species + 1) ~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2)*(Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)*(mean + sd), data=iris)
```

The latter just writes "char" instead of its contents...

The following "works"

```
eval(parse(text=paste("tabular(Heading(", "\"", char, "\"", ")*(Species + 1) ~ (n=1) + Format(digits=2)*(Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width)*(mean + sd), data=iris)", sep="")))
```

but I was hoping for a solution that would use an edited version of Heading...